# bash formatting issue - shows results in single line

Tags: bash, scripting, formatting

This script uses gcalcli to check 2 gmail calendars and send me a consolidated email with the day's appointments

```
#!/bin/bash

# variables
email1=myemail@here.net
dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

events ()
{
 for service in $(/bin/ls $dir/calendars/)
 do
  echo reminders for $service on $(date +%d-%m-%y)
  echo -------------------------------------------------------
  /usr/bin/gcalcli \
  --config-folder $dir/calendars/$service \
  agenda \
  --tsv \
  "`/bin/date -d 'now'`" \
  "`/bin/date -d 'now + 24 hours'`" \
  | /bin/grep -e 95 -e 96 -e 97 -e 99 \
  | /usr/bin/awk '{$3=$4=""; print $0}'
 done
}

echo $(events) | mail -s "reminders for $(date +%d-%m-%y)" $email1
```

My problem is that the results come in a single line, instead of one line per appointment.
How can I fix this?

Comment: This is not a free debugging service. Please provide a [mcve] and show your attempts to solve this so far. Oh, and for a start, paste your script to https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 1):

ok I found it, I just put $(events) in quotes "$(events)"

Comment: Why not just `events | mail ...`?